# resample irregularly spaced data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it somehow possible to use `resample` on irregularly spaced data? (I know that the documentation says it's for "resampling of regular time-series data", but I wanted to try if it works on irregular data, too. Maybe it doesn't, or maybe I am doing something wrong.)

In my real data, I have generally 2 samples per hour, the time difference between them ranging usually from 20 to 40 minutes. So I was hoping to resample them to a regular hourly series.

To test if I am using it right, I used some random list of dates that I already had, so it may not be a best example but at least a solution that works for it will be very robust. here it is:

```
    fraction  number                time
0   0.729797       0 2014-10-23 15:44:00
1   0.141084       1 2014-10-30 19:10:00
2   0.226900       2 2014-11-05 21:30:00
3   0.960937       3 2014-11-07 05:50:00
4   0.452835       4 2014-11-12 12:20:00
5   0.578495       5 2014-11-13 13:57:00
6   0.352142       6 2014-11-15 05:00:00
7   0.104814       7 2014-11-18 07:50:00
8   0.345633       8 2014-11-19 13:37:00
9   0.498004       9 2014-11-19 22:47:00
10  0.131665      10 2014-11-24 15:28:00
11  0.654018      11 2014-11-26 10:00:00
12  0.886092      12 2014-12-04 06:37:00
13  0.839767      13 2014-12-09 00:50:00
14  0.257997      14 2014-12-09 02:00:00
15  0.526350      15 2014-12-09 02:33:00
```

Now I want to resample these for example monthly:

```
df_new = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['time']))
df_new['fraction'] = df.fraction.resample('M',how='mean')
df_new['number'] = df.number.resample('M',how='mean')
```

But I get `TypeError: Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'` - unless I did something wrong with assigning the datetime index, it must be due to the irregularity?

So my questions are:

1. Am I using it correctly?
2. If 1==True, is there no straightforward way to resample the data?

(I only see a solution in first reindexing the data to get finer intervals, interpolate the values in between and then reindexing it to hourly interval. If it is so, then a question regarding the correct implementation of reindex will follow shortly.)

Comment: pandas version 0.18.1, python 2.7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly use `DatetimeIndex`, just set `'time'` as the index and pandas will take care of the rest, so long as your `'time'` column has been converted to datetime using [`pd.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) or some other method.  Additionally, you don't need to resample each column individually if you're using the same method; just do it on the entire DataFrame.

```
# Convert to datetime, if necessary.
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])

# Set the index and resample (using month start freq for compact output).
df = df.set_index('time')
df = df.resample('MS').mean()
```

The resulting output:

```
            fraction  number
time                        
2014-10-01  0.435441     0.5
2014-11-01  0.430544     6.5
2014-12-01  0.627552    13.5
```

Comment: I actually used the `DatetimeIndex` in response to the `TypeError`, hoping it would solve it, but it didn't. But thanks, the simplification actually works! I was following this example http://benalexkeen.com/resampling-time-series-data-with-pandas/ that probably overcomplicates it.